# GTM Macro to set GUA_ID based on domain/hostname/url

Tags: google-tag-manager

We have several websites. During set-up of GTM I was wondering if I needed to set-up 1 GTM-container for alle websites (and make it variable) or set-up 1 container per website. The latter seemed like a lot of manual config.

However, to achieve a more dynamic approach I was wondering if I can set the GUA ID depending on a url/hostname regex lookup table.

Making it more difficult: We have both different domains as same domains with subfolders for languages so the lookup table has to support both.

**My question**: will a macro lookup like this work or does a better method exist to achieve the same result?

See the image below as example

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookup table macro doesn't support regular expressions. You should use transitional custom JS-macro or tag in which you check your regexp's. Then you may push it to datalayer or return in macro used as a key in your lookup table

For example

## v1 - js tag

```
<script>
    categories=[
        /\/moscow\/.*kupit-kvartiru\/kvartiri-studii\//,
        /\/moscow\/.*kupit-kvartiru\/odnokomnatnie-kvartiri\//,
        /\/moscow\/.*kupit-kvartiru\/dvuhkomnatnie-kvartiri\//,
        /\/moscow\/.*kupit-kvartiru\/trehkomnatnie-kvartiri\//,
        /\/moscow\/.*kupit-kvartiru\/chetyrehkomnatnie-kvartiri\//,
        /\/moscow\/.*kupit-kvartiru\/bolshie-kvartiri\//
    ];
    for (i in categories) {
    if (RegExp(categories[i]).test({{url}})) {
            category_type_for_retargeting=categories[i].toString().slice(1,-1);
            dataLayer.push({
                'event'        : 'regex_event',
                'category'    : category_type_for_retargeting
            });
        }
    }

</script>
```

## v2 - js macro for lookup table

```
function() {
    categories=[
        /\/moscow\/.*kupit-kvartiru\/kvartiri-studii\//,
        /\/moscow\/.*kupit-kvartiru\/odnokomnatnie-kvartiri\//,
        /\/moscow\/.*kupit-kvartiru\/dvuhkomnatnie-kvartiri\//,
        /\/moscow\/.*kupit-kvartiru\/trehkomnatnie-kvartiri\//,
        /\/moscow\/.*kupit-kvartiru\/chetyrehkomnatnie-kvartiri\//,
        /\/moscow\/.*kupit-kvartiru\/bolshie-kvartiri\//
    ];
    for (i in categories) {
    if (RegExp(categories[i]).test({{url}})) {
            category_type_for_retargeting=categories[i].toString().slice(1,-1);
            return category_type_for_retargeting;
        }
    }
    return -1; //default value
}
```

## v3 - js macro as UA id

```
function() {
    categories={
        "UA-1234-1" : /\/moscow\/.*kupit-kvartiru\/kvartiri-studii\//,
        "UA-1234-2" : /\/moscow\/.*kupit-kvartiru\/odnokomnatnie-kvartiri\//,
        "UA-1234-3" : /\/moscow\/.*kupit-kvartiru\/dvuhkomnatnie-kvartiri\//,
        "UA-1234-4" : /\/moscow\/.*kupit-kvartiru\/trehkomnatnie-kvartiri\//,
        "UA-1234-5" : /\/moscow\/.*kupit-kvartiru\/chetyrehkomnatnie-kvartiri\//,
        "UA-1234-6" : /\/moscow\/.*kupit-kvartiru\/bolshie-kvartiri\//
    };
    for (i in categories) {
        if (RegExp(categories[i]).test({{url}})) return i;
    }
}
```